# file.read(integer) python read characters

Tags: python, file

As part of a task I must write a program that copies a number with a number of unknown digits from a file. Python language.

I have created a function which retains into int several digits containing the number.

The function to read from a file:

`file.read (1)` This way I managed to read one character. I tried to replace the number in my variable `file.read (myint)` - but the reading does not work. The program ran all the way, but nothing was called.

I tried before to convert `myint` to  int, float, long but to no avail.

Can anyone help?

Thanks .
I do not know where the discussion fits, I'd be happy to guide you.
sorry for my english..

[my code part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXL2x.png)

[my code part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbMDq.png)

Comment: please show us the code you've written so far.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your problem is not clear to me. If you show your code as it is now, that would probably clarify things. Also, your question "Can anyone help" is much too vague for this site. Please read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you trying to read a text file and copy the contents into another file? Question is very vague

Comment: i am trying to read char after char from the file and save the first number "full" from the file.
for example, in the file:

7264 jsdovni.

i want to read into "myint":
7264